# installing Auto Sklearn in Ubuntu 18

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I have been trying to install Auto Sklearn for a week now

and keep failing

different errors each time

Now I get this error
[image]

[image]

I tried many slolutions but non work

I tried installing swig using

[image]

i am very new to Ubuntu

help appreciated

Comment: its install not intall

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found the way to install Auto Sklearn

Please note that I have fresh installtion of Ubuntu

It is long but it works (at least worked for me)

1-

```
Install Ubuntu from Microsoft Store
```

2-

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

3-

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
```

4-

```
sudo apt-get update
```

5-

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

6-

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

7-

```
sudo apt-get install swig
```

8-

```
pip3 uninstall numpy
```

9-

```
pip3 uninstall numpy
```

10-

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

11-

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

12-

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/automl/auto-sklearn/master/requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip3 install
```

13-

```
pip3 uninstall numpy
```

14-

```
pip3 uninstall numpy
```

15-

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

16-

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

17-

```
pip3 install numpy
```

18-

```
pip3 install auto-sklearn
```

Answer (score 2):

You have typed install wrongly. Copy and paste the following:

```
sudo apt install swig
```

It's a good idea to install the following too:

```
sudo apt install python3-dev build-essential
```